# Rails: Replace Submit Button With Pure HTML

Tags: forms, submit, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple form with several hidden fields:

```
= form_for item.votes.new, remote: true do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :value, value; 1
  = f.hidden_field :voteable_id, value: item.id
  = f.hidden_field :voteable_type, value: item.class.name
  = f.submit
```

Instead of a submit button, however, I want to use a div:

```
div.arrow.arrow--up
```

I know this is possible using javascript, but can I somehow manage this purely with Rails? For instance, something like:

```
= f.submit "", type: :html, partial: 'up_arrow'
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to use the submit tag or javascript. You can, however, use CSS to format the submit button like any other html element.

http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2009/04/24/how-to-style-a-submit-button-in-css/